# How to use read_line function with Rust's serialport crate

Tags: rust, serial-port

I am working with the [serialport crate](https://crates.io/crates/serialport) on a raspberry. The given example with `port.read` works fine. However `port.read_to_end` or `port.read_to_string` does not work, I get a timeout.
Can anybody explain this behavior? The two functions read all bytes until EOF. I am sending test strings with null termination.

I am more interested in a `read_line` function. But this is not directly supported with the serialport crate, is it? Can I use the BufRead trait for this?

Comment: Null termination is not equivalent to EOF. EOF, or end-of-file, will only happen when **no more data can be read**, a.k.a. the serial connection closing. You can in fact wrap it in a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) and use the [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait on the `BufReader` in order to call `read_line` or read until a null byte with `read_until(0, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Aplet123! I was not aware of this.
Can you give me a hint on how to use the BufReader? What have I pass to BufReader::new()? The port itself does not work: method not found in `std::io::BufReader<std::boxed::Box<dyn serialport::SerialPort>>`

Comment: Can you include relevant code (preferably a [mre])? Also, are you sure you spelled `new` correctly?

Comment: @Aplet123 I forget `use std::io::BufRead;` Now it works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a minimal example with `read_line`. Works when TX and RX are connected.

```
use serialport;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let mut serial_port = serialport::new("/dev/serial0", 9600)
        .timeout(Duration::from_millis(1000))
        .open()
        .expect("Failed to open serial port");

    let output = "This is a test.\n".as_bytes();
    serial_port.write(output).expect("Write failed!");
    serial_port.flush().unwrap();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(serial_port);
    let mut my_str = String::new();
    reader.read_line(&mut my_str).unwrap();

    println!("{}", my_str);
}
```

Comment: For some reason `reader.read_line` hangs forever unless I create the `BufReader` with a very small buffer size. No problems like this: `let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(1,serial_port);` Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @user643011 The only reason I can think of is the obvious one: there are no line breaks in the input data and the read_line function waits forever. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks for there reply! There are frequent line breaks in the input data, and with capacity `1` parsing the serial output works great: it returns exactly complete lines, as soon as they are finished. It also never returns incomplete or partial lines.
But with a regular `BufReader::new(serial_port);` it does not work. I am not using a `timeout` on the serial port like you do. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @user643011 The example above does not work for me if I omit the timeout. I get a TimedOut when unwrapping the read_line function. I am testing on Ubuntu with an USB serial adapter. Maybe the behavior with timeout=0 is on your platform buggy? Does it work if you add a timeout?